# Número de seeds em um torrent

Tags: php

Como ver o número de *seeds* que um Torrent tem por PHP? Depende do tracker? Como fazer isso nos *torrents* do Pirate Bay?

Comment: Sugiro que você leia o guia [ask]. Mostrar que você fez uma pesquisa inicial e tentou alguma coisa valorizam sua pergunta. O contrário do que está acontecendo agora :/ . . . Sei que tem perguntas semelhantes aqui que recebem votos positivos e respostas, parece que você pegou a maré desfavorável. Enfim, fica a dica.

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente, o jeito é fazer um [*scrape*](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_.27scrape.27_Convention) a partir do *tracker*:

- [How To Know the number of seeds/peers for a torrent in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2865868/1287812)
- [Sending scrape request for getting torrent's seeds and peers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5140300/1287812)

Tem [uma indicação](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5879861/1287812) para usar a API do [Bitsnoop](http://bitsnoop.com/info/api.html) (não testado).

São [só 26 resultados](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20torrent%20seed) buscando por "torrent seed" dentro da tag PHP do Stack Overflow.

Comment: No fim, fiquei curioso à respeito. Não votei pra fechar e dei um voto positivo na pergunta. @user3517672, espero que sirva de base para você iniciar os testes e trazer perguntas mais orientadas ao código pra cá. Boa sorte!